# How to derive this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering how to derive this series?

[image]

I know that

[image]

But not sure how to solve the first one. Please give me some hints. Thanks a lot.

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty  r x^{r-1}=\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{d (x^r)}{dx}=\frac{d\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^r\right)}{dx}$$

Now, $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^r=\frac x{1-x}=-1+\frac1{1-x}$$ for $|x|<1$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the d here is not the differentiation. It is a variable d (which is in the summation).

Comment: @SamoJerom, sorry for the confusion. Edited